# Need help configuring Castle-Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor

I have these base interfaces and providers in one assembly (Assembly1):

```
public interface IEntity
{
}

public interface IDao
{
}

public interface IReadDao<T> : IDao
    where T : IEntity
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
}

public class NHibernate<T> : IReadDao<T>
    where T : IEntity
{
    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

And I have this implementation inside another assembly (Assembly2):

```
public class Product : IEntity
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public interface IProductDao : IReadDao<Product> 
{
    IEnumerable<Product> GetByCode(string code);
}

public class ProductDao : NHibernate<Product>, IProductDao
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetByCode(string code)
    {
        return new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get `IRead<Product>` and `IProductDao` from the container.
I am using this registration:

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Assembly2")
        .BasedOn(typeof(IReadDao<>)).WithService.FromInterface(),
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Assembly1")
        .BasedOn(typeof(IReadDao<>)).WithService.Base());
```

The `IReadDao<Product>` works great. The container gives me `ProductDao`. But if I try to get `IProductDao`, the container throws `ComponentNotFoundException`. How can I correctly configure the registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing your Assembly2 registration to use all interfaces:

```
AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Assembly2").BasedOn(typeof(IReadDao<>))
  .WithService.Select((t, baseType) => t.GetInterfaces());
```